# Scaling of a notch filter

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, infinite-impulse-response

Let's say I have an IIR filter that is a notch type with a peak at -20db. How do I modify the coefficients of the filter so that the peak is at -10 db for example?

I know I can scale the denominator coefficients so that the global peak amplitude can be set, but it affects the whole filter, which I don't want.

Here is what I want :
[image: a]

Comment: There is no way to just change the depth of the notch without affecting the frequency response at all frequencies. The question is _how much_ of a change in the response at other frequencies you can tolerate. If the answer is `None` then there is no answer.

Comment: You should provide an explanation of how you derived your filter coefficients, or at least what your coefficients are.

Comment: okay . follow me here : suppose i mix two signals : one is a full allpass with magnitude = 1 on all frequencies . If i mix it with the notch filter : (a+b)/2. the bottom frequency (-20db) is 0.1. It will become : (1+0.1)/2=0.55. so the notch is affected. Ins't there a way to report that on the coefficients?

Comment: There is a way to achieve the same result by changing the filter coefficients - however you need to change to process by which you obtained the coefficients, there is no one 'thing you do to filter coefficients to increase the notch amplitude in notch filters'.

Comment: Note that it's hard to go in the direction that you want, as you essentially need to redesign the filter. However, if you wanted to go the other way (turn a -10 dB notch into a -20 dB notch), a simple approach that is worth considering is just applying the filter twice in cascade. This will also have the effect of doubling any passband ripple, however (you'll get an effective squaring of the frequency response).

Comment: @PAK : yes i'm aware of that, computing new coefficients would solve everything. But i want to reduce the filter design computational cost and to design once and for all the filter then scaling it down. But can't we just consider two filters in parallel : one allpass of equation : y = 1 * x and the other one being the notch filter. Can we make one filter from these two parallel ones? (by adding the coefficients, dunno)

Comment: @Jason : yes that's an idea though i would prefer go the other way, ie computing the highest peak and then scaling it down, because how do you get a -5 db from a -10 db ?

Answer (score 1):

You show a pretty narrow notch, are you trying to notch out a tone? If so, maybe you could use an Inverse Chebyshev, and move the -10 dB pt in the notch to your tone frequency.
[image: Plot of 2 Pole Inverse Chebyshev Notch]

Comment: hi Dan. What i'm trying to do is to compute once and for all a notch filter at its greatest height (lowest peak), and to apply just a scaling factor to it. This is to cancel the design computation factor of each filter.